# Local Database Parse Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, parse-platform

I have an application in Xcode, and the application linked a database on Parse .. It brings news from Parse and displays it in TableView ..

But the problem is, if the user had lost contact with the Internet, it does not display anything, just a white screen
I want to show me the latest news that have appeared since the last connection

Comment: You need create local database. Retrieve data from Parse and save in local  Application db. So, previous data will display on app without internet connection.

Comment: Bit old but should get you in the right direction http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1

Comment: @sbarow is right!
Or in just check your network status, if network is fail just load the data from your last data response you have or if your connection completed and you get proper response just then update your data

Answer (score 0):

Parse has a good way to cache data if the connection is lost.
Try adding:

```
query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache;
```

to your query and run it. First with and then without connection.
This is a good guide that explains it a little bit deeper: https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Constants/PFCachePolicy.html

Cheers!

Comment: I think you meant query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache;